# how to run any specific request from collection in postman?

Tags: postman, newman

I have a collection with 5 subfolders. Let's say 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Every folder contains at least 1 request. I want to run one request from folder 3 only. Is it possible to run it via terminal?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command to target the specific folder or multiple folders:

```
--folder <name>
```

Run requests within a particular folder/folders in a collection. Multiple folders can be specified by using `--folder` multiple times, like so:

```
--folder f1 --folder f2
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @contapost - I thought I would highlight the command in an image as it was should but I should have not been lazy and typed it out. :)

Comment: Thanks  but my query is related to some specific APi. Let say my folder 2 is have 6 endpingt and I want to hit any specif one. Is it doable ? @Danny

Comment: If you put that single request in a single folder...i don't think that it can be pointed at a specific request with a folder. You might be able to achieve this with a workflow and setting the `postman.setNextRequest(request_name)` value.